# Can I make ASP.net applications with Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Just curious. Right now I'm using Visual C# Express 2008 for Desktop Apps, and Visual Web Developer 2008 Express for ASP.Net Apps.

Can I download Visual Studio 2010 and use it for free for a one stop shop development IDE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 can be used as your one stop development IDE but the non-expression versions are not free :(